# Extending the exponential indicator function to the $n$ variable case

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A trick I often see in probability texts for binary classification relies on assigning the class vector

$t = (t_1, \ldots, t_n)$

Where all $t_n$ are either $1$ or $0$.

The simplest place you see this is the Bernoulli distribution, where the probability of each class is $P(x) = a^x(1-a)^{1-x}$. When $x=1$, the right term disappears, and when $x=0$ the left term disappears.

How can I extend this to an arbitrary number of classes?

Comment: For $0\leqslant x\leqslant n-1$ and $0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$, $$\mathbf 1_{x=k}=\prod_{i=1\\ i\ne k}^{n-1}\frac{x-i}{k-i}$$ For example, $$a^{(x-1)(x-2)/2}b^{-x(x-2)}c^{x(x-1)/2}$$ equals $a$ if $x=0$, $b$ if $x=1$ and $c$ if $x=2$.